# Problems with inheriting permisions in a folder system with samba

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a server with Ubuntu 20.04 that provides some services.

A few weeks ago I was asked to create a shared folder compatible with windows,so obviously samba was the option so created a new Samba share,  forced the permissions that I wanted for the folders (with commands directory mask, force directory mode, directory security mask and force directory security mode) and set in all folders the correct owner and permits, and then the umask parameter that I wanted and the g+s bit on so they will inherit the parents group permissions, set those and let people start to create their labyrinth of folders and subfolders.

The problem I'm stuck at is that some times, when they create new subfolders inside those folders (and I mean usually in like 4 or 5 levels down of subfolders) they have problems that the folders are created with the group ownership of the creator.

I could have  tried with the Force group variable in the samba config (that is not set currently) but that will make me made a different samba definition for each folder in the shared folder, and then I need to make a new samba definition manually each time that a folder is created in the root of the shared folder, so I want to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: What is not clear from your post is if you want all subfolders to be writeable to every client user. Or do you want each user to have their own subfolder that only they can access.

Comment: I have one big folder,that is like the root and is accesible for anybody,an then there I have a bunch of folders (like 10) that have different group permissions depending on who can acces it.